# How to insert mean and standard deviation within a correlation matrix in stargazer

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, stargazer

I have seen some publication quality correlation tables that contain in addition to other variables the mean and standard deviation within the table. I prepared my correlation matrix and used stargazer to output, but there is no way to to include the mean and standard deviation. I have searched extensively but this is not anywhere online.
Note that stargazer produces the desired output of the mean/standard deviation table and correlation table, but fails to combine both into one table.
So, I want
[image]

Using the `summary.stat` function within stargazer does not solve this issue by the way. Any help how to do this within stargazer? Thanks!

Comment: You're going to want to change your post to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to get the best answers quickly. However, in the PDF that stargazer includes with their library, they explain how to add things like SE to a correlation table. Have you looked at it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a `stargazer` answer (sorry!), but I'm still leaving this here in case anyone finds it useful.

This result can be achieved rather easily with the [`datasummary` family of functions from the `modelsummary` package.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) (Disclaimer: I am the maintainer.)

First, the `datasummary` function can be used to draw summary tables with arbitrary statistics, defined by the user. In this case, we can do:

```
library(modelsummary)

dat <- mtcars[, c("hp", "mpg", "drat")]

datasummary(All(dat) ~ Mean + SD, data = dat)
```

[image]

Then, the `datasummary_correlation` can produce a correlation table:

```
datasummary_correlation(dat)
```

[image]

Finally, we use the `output` argument to save the correlation table as a `data.frame`, and we feed this data.frame to the `add_columns` argument of `datasummary` to combine the two tables:

```
library(modelsummary)

corr <- datasummary_correlation(dat, output = "data.frame")[, 2:3]

datasummary(All(dat) ~ Mean + SD, data = dat, add_columns = corr)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a helpful response. Thanks @Vincent. Yes, model summary appears to be better suited for this manipulation. I was just wondering if this could be done in stargazer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Scientific publications use canonical formats for certain tables, for example for correlation tables, among others, in order to maintain a certain editorial and graphical style. The table you are looking into in an example of such a canonical format. See American Psychological Association required style [here](http://The%20following%20sample%20tables%20illustrate%20how%20to%20set%20up%20tables%20in%20APA%20Style.%20When%20possible,%20use%20a%20canonical,%20or%20standard,%20format%20for%20a%20table%20rather%20than%20inventing%20your%20own%20format.) as an example.
I believe there is no such function to produce such an automated output, but it can be produced in the following way.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(corrr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)


df  <- data.frame(Var1 = rnorm(100), Var2 = rnorm(100), Var3 = rnorm(100), Var4 = rnorm(100))


options(knitr.kable.NA = '')

df1 <- df %>% 
  correlate(diagonal = 1) %>%
  shave(upper = TRUE) 

df1$Mean <- unlist(lapply(df, mean))

df1$sd <- unlist(lapply(df, sd))

names(df1) <- c("Variable", 1, 2, 3, 4, "Mean", "s.d.")

df1 %>% select(Variable, Mean, `s.d.`, 1, 2, 3, 4) %>%
  kbl() %>% kable_classic(full_width = F)
```

[image]